# Is there an option to have pinned posts on the main site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I know this might need to be a feature request on Meta.SE but I wanted to know if there might already be some option to do this.

I'm thinking of how we can have information available for new (and not-so-new) users straight from the main page (because as previously established, most new users don't look at the Help Center).

I think there are several Meta posts that are crucial for new users to understand this community and how and what kind of questions we answer. There is the all-famous [Friends, We Are Not Philosophers](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/friends-we-are-not-philosophers?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C17.0846) post, but others such as the recent [Formal Logic](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5130/is-this-formal-logic-topic-more-appropriate-at-math-stackexchange) post (there might be a better one answered in the past but it's got good voting ratio).

If we can put several links in a banner on the main page, in such a way that it's screaming "read me" (think like HNQ but in a bigger text and higher in the panel) it might help new users to better understand how this site works (and hopefully prevent unwarranted questions that floods our Queues).

So:

1. We need mod input to understand if it's even possible.
2. We need to decide if we want it.
3. If those 2 requirements are met, we need to choose which posts will show up there.

Comment: I don't think there is a possibility for the main site, but only the FAQ-tag for the meta (which does something similar to your request). Would you like to propose a different set of FAQ-questions?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking: I'm sure it's possible for mods to edit the sidebar. It's done on [med SE](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions) to warn people from posting personal (medical) questions etc. Law SE also has a smaller warning IIRC.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking my point is to try and make sure that users who don't look at the FAQ (probably a big percentage of new users) would have it right in their face.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to pin questions from the main site, but there are two mechanisms to "pin" questions from the meta site in a way that makes the visible on the main site (at least in desktop browsers):

1. Adding the tag [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) to the question. Only moderators can do this. The tag is automatically removed after some time, i.e. [roughly one month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281797/340816)..
2. By creating an "event" with a start and end date. The event is described in a meta question, so you essentially get a link to that meta question. Only moderators can create events and "events" can last longer than a month. For example, on [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) (where I am a moderator), reading challenges are "events" that last for two months.

Fizz's comment mentions editing the sidebar, but as far as I know, this requires intervention by a CM; I am not aware of a mechanism that is available to moderators.